# Eevee render contains unexpected flare

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I encountered a problem with Eevee rendering, where some frames contain these bright spots, pictured below. Is there any solution?
I guess it may be related to volume fog, but changing these parameters has not helped so far.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you've lowered your volumetric tile size?

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem. This problem will appear after the Bloom is turned on. Modifying the clamp can solve this problem, but I don't know the principle.